# OpenERP - Python development environment

Tags: odoo

I have installed Odoo v8 on VM, with Ubuntu. I am using GEDIT for editing .py and .xml files. Is there a Python development environment out there where I can develop, and more importantly, debug my Python code? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think this question would be more relevant on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), since it is asking for a software recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse + PyDev convenient for OpenERP/Odoo-Python.  For quick computations, apply patches, Idle is great.

Also  Aptana Studio (http://www.aptana.com/) is good and it's alongside GIT to have local version control. It is easy to either deploy locally or push the changes to a remote GIT repo.

[here is good anwer given by community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Eclipse, which is popularly used for Odoo development. It helps in debugging also.

Comment: Eclipse is a logical choice for a VM since Eclipse is in the Ubuntu Software Center and PyCharm Community Edition isn't.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) too it's very good one.